# Any standard way of passing lines?

Tags: ros, messages

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to pass lines between nodes. I can easily make my own line message but want use a standard message if possible. I haven't found any obvious ones.

Is there a standard message for passing a line/lines?

Currently I'm considering just co-opting Polygon.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29730/any-standard-way-of-passing-lines?/) by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2743 on 2012-03-14

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) on 2012-03-14**:
Polygon would get my vote. visualization_msgs/Marker explicitly handles lines (and line lists/strips), but it's a bit clunky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would suggest Polygon.

What's odd is that the Point32 message says to use Point whenever possible, but the Polygon message uses Point32.  The message API seems to contradict itself in this regard.

Perhaps @tfoote can weight in on this design decision.

---

Originally posted by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) with karma: 6414 on 2012-03-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) on 2012-03-14**:
I tried marking this as a community wiki answer, since @dlaz really answered it first, so he should get the imaginary internet points before me.  Marking an existing answer doesn't seem to work, though.

**Comment by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) on 2012-03-14**:
Hah, I appreciate the thought. I started it out as an answer, but felt like it wasn't really an answer, so switched to a comment.

**Comment by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) on 2012-03-14**:
No problem, I'm up voting your comments as a consolation prize.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-03-15**:
The reason for using Point32 is for space reasons.  It's the same reason point clouds use Point32. When you start sending large polygons 64bits of precision starts to use a lot of bandwidth.